# Find weight given it can be up to $34 $ times more than $3^{-2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

A newborn baby chicken weighs $3^{-2}$ pounds ($3$ raised to negative $2$). If an adult chicken can weigh up to $34$ times more than the newborn chicken, how much does an adult chicken weigh?

A. $9$ pounds

B. $10$ pounds

C. $64$ pounds

D. $144/9$ pounds

#### Progress

I tried converting it to fraction. $1/3^2$ then $1/9$. The result is $34/9$, not in the choices. I think something's wrong with my process or maybe it's just the quiz itself. Just trying to make sure.

Comment: I tried converting it to fraction. 1/3^2 then 1/9. The result is 34/9, not in the choices. I think something's wrong with my process or maybe it's just the quiz itself. Just trying to make sure.

Comment: I know this is a really old question, but is it possible that the $34$ is actually supposed to be $3^4$? That would fit with the usage of $3^{-2}$ for the newborn weight, and that interpretation allows one of the answers to be correct, no matter how you interpret the dubious "times more than".

Answer (score 1):

Your answer of $34/9$ is correct. The "up to" doesn't help, either, as you are correct that none of the choices satisfy that.